# Manipulate object before replay it, in the "next" command

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that return some data with ReplaySubject:

```
this.metadata.next(this.list);
```

the problem is that some component add some data to the list.someObject,
and another component influenced from it.

there is a way to do:

```
 this.metadata.next(_.cloneDeep(this.list));
```

Or another solution?

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you are asking. Whenever you pass  any value into `this.metadata.next()` the subscribers will receive the value that you pass in, not a reference to `this.list`. Why do you need to clone it?

Comment: I do not know on what basis do you say that, but from what happens to me, is sent referents, not value.

Comment: which version of RxJs are you using?

Comment: the latest - 5.2.0

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle and i'll help you